# How to get size from a NetworkImage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a class that should return the network Image size but it's not working I don't know why.
So the way I want to work is that the image URL is passed to the class and then the _ImageSize function is called on the class constructor and sets the height and width property of the class

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageSize {
  double height;
  double width;
  final String imgName;

  ImageSize(this.imgName) {
    _imageSize();
  }

  void _imageSize() {
    Future<ui.Image> _getImageInfo() {
      Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
      NetworkImage(this.imgName).resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
        ImageStreamListener(
          (ImageInfo info, bool _) => completer.complete(info.image),
        ),
      );
      return completer.future;
    }

    _getImageInfo().then((size) {
      print(size);
      height = size.height.toDouble();
      width = size.width.toDouble();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}

main() async {
  double height = ImageSize(
      'https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'
  ).height;
  print(height);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use following code

```
class ImageSize {
  double height;
  double width;
  final String imgName;

  ImageSize(this.imgName) {
    _imageSize();
  }

  void _imageSize() {
    Future<Size> _getImageInfo() {
      Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
      Image image = Image.network(this.imgName);
      image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
        ImageStreamListener(
          (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
            var myImage = image.image;
            Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
            completer.complete(size);
          },
        ),
      );
      return completer.future;
    }

    _getImageInfo().then((size) {
      print(size);
      height = size.height.toDouble();
      width = size.width.toDouble();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm still getting null